# Scrollbar jumps down when div go to position: fixed (but only when using the scrollbar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to make a simple sticky nav bar that hides on scroll down and goes visible on scroll up. It works like I want it to when scrolling with the scroll wheel, but when scrolling by clicking and dragging the scrollbar, it jumps to the bottom when #nav-wrap goes from `display: absolute` to `display: fixed`.

Any idea what's going on, and what can be done?

[Here's the JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/garland_briggs/jta67yvd/)

### HTML

```
<div id="nav-wrap">
    <div id="nav" class="clear">
        <nav>
            <h1>Navbar</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>item 1</li>
                <li>item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    height: 1000px;
}
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
#nav-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

### JS

```
var previousScroll = 0,
    headerOrgOffset = $('#nav').height();
var nav = $('#nav-wrap');
var stickyNav = false;
var topPos = true;

nav.height($('#nav').height());

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (currentScroll > headerOrgOffset) {
        if (currentScroll > previousScroll) { // hvis skroller nedover
            if (topPos) {
                nav.css('position', 'fixed');
                nav.hide();
                topPos = false;
            } else {
                nav.slideUp();
                stickyNav = false;
            }
        } else if (currentScroll < previousScroll) { // hvis skroller oppover
            if (!topPos) {
                nav.slideDown();
                stickyNav = true;
            }
        }
    } else if (currentScroll == 0) {
        nav.css('position', 'absolute');
        topPos = true;
    }
    previousScroll = currentScroll;
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jta67yvd/1/ The element should be fixed. Not prettfied but it is a minor change and has your desired effect. This is a cool way to have a header on a site, very modern. It can definitely be improved, but just make sure the header wrapper is fixed not absolute.

Comment: With your solution it works the first time you drag down the scrollbar, but the second time it jumps down again. Also, the header is supposed to scroll up together with the content when scrolling down from the top of the page.

Comment: Oh I just read you want the header to scroll with the content I made a fiddle here using bootstrap for a much better suited header http://jsfiddle.net/jta67yvd/8/ so you want the header to scroll with the content then hide itself when scrolling upward? Could you provide a real example, sorry if I misunderstood. I am just used to design having the header hidden then shown upon scrolling up similar  to medium https://medium.com/@jakek/my-year-with-a-distraction-free-iphone-and-how-to-start-your-own-experiment-6ff74a0e7a50

Comment: The fiddle above does not fit your needs because I just reread your needs in your post above. I think it simplifies it though. The jQuery simply says if the page is scrolling down do this else if its going up then do this. It would be best to use CSS to handle any effects within that.

Comment: So one more question, if the header scrolls with page flow then yes it should be fixed if you're talking about having the header in viewport while the page is going down, when the page scrolls up what do you want to happen? Actually re-reading I think that fiddle may be your solution? Obviously needs a few tweaks with the `<main>` content. Let me know I would be glad to help sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Actually, the medium scrollbar is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. It's currently working like it should in my JSFiddle, with two exceptions:

1. there's a bug when _clicking_ and dragging the scrollbar downwards (the scrollbar "jumps" down) and 
2. when the user scrolls up (in a smooth motion), I want the navbar to scroll _together with the content_ like on medium.

I want to get rid of #1. Next up is trying to achieve #2.